# Should I include the dependency spring-boot-starter into my custom spring boot starter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

If I create a custom spring boot starter module, Do I need to include the dependency `spring-boot-starter` ?

In the [spring boot's github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters) :

- some starters add the dependency `spring-boot-starter` to its `pom.xml` ([spring-boot-starter-web](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/pom.xml), [spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/pom.xml))
- some others starters doesn't ([spring-boot-starter-log4j2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/pom.xml), [spring-boot-starter-undertow](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-undertow/pom.xml), [spring-boot-starter-tomcat](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/pom.xml)).

Is there a reason to no adding it into the dependencies ?

Comment: there is no need to include the dependency for spring-boot-starter. Only if you need the transitiv dependencies for your own starter. But your starter should not start with spring-*. The keyword spring is reserved. The prefix should be the name for your starter. for example see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter

Comment: I already know my starter should not start with spring-*, this is not my question. In the baldung example, the starter project includes the dependency to spring-boot-starter wheareas it doesn't use it into the custom starter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your starter depends on `spring-boot-starter`, any application that depends only on your starter will have all the dependencies that it needs to be a Spring Boot application. Generally speaking, this is how you want a starter to behave.

`spring-boot-stater-log4j2`, `spring-boot-starter-undertow`, and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` are slightly different as they are not intended to be used on their own. The [Spring Boot documentation calls them technical starters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter). They are intended to be used alongside an existing starter to change the underlying technology that's used. For example, if you are building a web application, you would depend on `spring-boot-starter-web`. This starter uses Tomcat as the embedded container by default. If you want to swap to Undertow, you'd exclude `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and add a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-undertow` alongside your `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Use Undertow instead -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What if the client project uses a different spring boot version to the version specified in my starter project ? When including my custom starter project, he will get two versions of spring-boot, spring-core etc...

Comment: They won’t get two versions. The build system will ensure that only a single version of each dependency is used. The most common way to control which version is by using Spring Boot’s dependency management.

Comment: you are right, maven will pick the nearest (in the dependency tree) spring dependency if multiple are found